# Преобразовать массив объектов в HashMap

Tags: java

*Хочется странного*

Есть массив объектов. У каждого объекта есть уникальное поле `id`. Хочется преобразовать этот массив в HashMap с ключами, равными этим `id`

Да, я знаю как сделать такое через цикл. Но может есть какой более элегантный путь, стримы, волшебные касты и т.д. о которых я просто не знаю?

```
class Accident{
    public int id;
    ....
}


Accidents[] accArray = getAccidentsByRetrofitAndGson();
Map accidents<Integer,Accident> = new HashMap();
// Вот вместо этого?
for(Accident acc:accidents){
    accidents.put(acc.id, acc);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

С помощью метода `forEach` из `Stream` можно так:

```
Map<Integer, Accident> accidents = new HashMap<>();
Stream.of(accArray).forEach(e -> accidents.put(e.id, e));
```

---

По аналогии с вариантом из комментария @post_zeew:

```
Map<Integer, Accident> accidents;
accidents = Stream.of(accArray).collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.id, e -> e));
```

Comment: IDEA в лице компилятора ругается на маппинг, если явно не кастовать в `Integer`

Comment: @I.Perevoz однако же этот код [работает](https://goo.gl/zLu9N6).

Comment: Я написал об этом для тех, кто используя данный код в IDEA будет удивлен тому, "почему не запускается"